# Maximum likelihood estimator when log likelihood equals constant

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to find the MLE for a parameter $\theta = \alpha$ when $\alpha = 0$ (I am doing hypothesis testing, and $H_0 : \alpha = 0$, $H_1 : \alpha \not = 0$).

Under the null hypothesis, the log likelihood function equals 1 s.t.

$L_{\theta_0}(\alpha | x ) = 1$

$log[ L_{\theta_0}(\alpha | x ) ]= log(1)$

$\frac{d}{d\alpha}log[ L_{\theta_0}(\alpha | x ) ]= 0$

How do I proceed in finding the MLE? Usually, you would set the value equal to 0, solve for your parameter, and check the second derivative to verify that the value is a maximum.

Comment: What makes you say "log likelihood function equals 1" or "$L_{\theta_0}(\alpha | x ) = 1$"?

Comment: The likelihood function is $(1+\alpha)*(x^\alpha)$, so when the null hypothesis holds that $\alpha = 0$, the likelihood function goes to 1 since $(1+0)*(x^0) = 1$. @Henry

Comment: You cannot meaningfully calculate a maximum likelihood estimate of $\alpha$ if you are assuming $\alpha$ takes a specific value: if $\alpha=0$ then $\alpha=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that $x$ is always in the interval $(0,1)$ so $\log(x) \lt 0$.

If $L(\alpha | x ) = (1+\alpha)x^\alpha$ and

$\log( L(\alpha | x ) ) = \log(1+\alpha) +\alpha \log(x)$ and

$\frac{d}{d\alpha}\log( L(\alpha | x ) ) = \frac{1}{1+\alpha} + \log(x)$, then

given $x$, the maximum likelihood estimate of $\alpha$ is $\frac{1}{-\log(x)}-1$.

This will not be your null hypothesis of $\alpha =0$ unless $x=\exp(-1)$ exactly.  But it may be close enough. You need to do [likelihood-ratio testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test) or [relative likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Relative_likelihood) to find out whether the difference is significant.

*Added:* it may be easier to avoid using a maximum likelihood estimate to test your null hypothesis.  For example, if $\alpha=1$ then you have a uniform distribution, so taking a two-sided test, the probability that $x$ is in the interval $[0.025,0.975]$ would be $0.95$ under the null hypothesis and you would fail to reject it if $x$ is in that range.

Comment: I'm trying to identify the rejection region for a likelihood ratio test, specifically for $H_0 : \alpha = 0$ and $H_1 : \alpha \not = 0$.